# Is it possible that not every contributor can publish draft pages?

Tags: publishing-page, version

I have the "pages" document library and there are 10 users have contribute permissions. All 10 users can publish draft pages. Also draft pages created by someone else. I would like to avoid that all 10 users can publish these pages. Only 2 users need to be able to publish pages.

But all 10 users allowed to see all the draft versions. How can I implement this?

Comment: You could use an approval workflow maybe?

Comment: is that the only solution?